# MongoDB Compass import corrupts documents

Tags: mongodb, dump, mongodb-compass, mongoimport, mongoexport

## Description

It's not the first time I'm facing the issue when importing a  collection using MongoDB Compass.

The sequence of actions:

1. Export the collection from **remote** MongoDB using MongoDB Compass.

> Select collection to export -> **Collection** tab -> **Export Collection** -> **Export Full Collection** -> **Select Fields** -> **Select output** -> **Json** -> **Export**

It gives me json output with all fields (here is an example with only one document, the rest are deleted by myself after exporting the full collection, just to paste here):

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fecb5013bc3165ef52597d2"
  },
  "external_id": "536219641",
  "internal_id": "2503dbfe-4ada-11eb-869d-0050560c0060",
  "surname": "Surname",
  "name": "Name",
  "middle_name": "MiddleName",
  "birth_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "593654400000"
    }
  },
  "document": {
    "series": "1111",
    "number": "2222222"
  },
  "income": {
    "salary_amount": 100000
  },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "type": "MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER",
      "isActive": true,
      "value": "99966677722"
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.example.domain.Person",
  "has_сontracts": true,
  "citizenship_alfa_code": "RU",
  "marital_status": "OTHER",
  "created_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1609348353000"
    }
  }
}]
```

2. Open my **local** DB with MongoDB Compass, then:

> I'm creating the empty collection to perform import in there -> select
> collection -> **Collection** tab -> **Import Data** -> **Select file**
> -> **Import**

---

## The expectations and the actual result

When that collection is imported, I expect to see the following (just as on my remote DB):

[image]

But I see this:

[image]

**Almost all fields are ignored and some fields that imported are with broken nesting!**

---

## The question

Why do I experience such behaviour with MongoDB Compass? Is it a bug or something? And how to fix this issue to perform import properly with MongoDB Compass?

---

## What I have tried

Well, I have found the way to perform import properly, but **without** MongoDB Compass, using `mongoimport` from my terminal directly, **but with extra option** `--jsonArray` :

```
mongoimport --host localhost --db mylocaldb --collection person --drop --file person.json --jsonArray
```

However if I try `mongoimport` without `--jsonArray` flag, then it fails with the following message:

```
2023-02-12T00:36:08.961+0400    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2023-02-12T00:36:08.968+0400    dropping: mylocaldb.person
2023-02-12T00:36:08.974+0400    Failed: cannot decode array into a primitive.D
2023-02-12T00:36:08.974+0400    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

---

## Notes (UPDATED)

- After some investigastions thanks to [rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs), we established that this problem occurs when there is at least field with name "document" in collection documents. If we change the field name "document" to "doc", the import works correctly. Probably MongoDB Compass is using the field name "document" for some internal reason and when an imported document has the same field name, bad things happen. **Idk if there are some others "fragile" field names that can lead to the same effect when importing collection with MongoDB Compass.**
- To reproduce the issue you can use my json as a collection for import to Mongo DB with Mongo DB Compass, at least, using the versions of MongoDB/MongoDB Compass I specified below.
- Software:

  - **Remote Mongo DB version**: 4.2.7 Community
  - **Local Mongo DB version**: 4.2.7 Community
  - **MongoDB Compass version**: 1.35.0 (1.35.0)

Comment: Using the same version of Compass, but more recent versions of the MongoDB server (remote: 5.0.14, local: 6.2.0), I performed the same sequence of export/import with the entire [weatherdata.data collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/sample-data/sample-weather/) (10000 documents) and everything worked properly.  If you select just a few documents for import, does it work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs ty for your reply. I cannot select a few documents during import in my compass, since there is no such option. Only full import is there. But I face the same issue I described with only one document (see the json I provided). Could you try to import my json as a collection to your local db and give a feedback?

Comment: Wow!  I think you found a Compass bug.  If I try to import the document, as is, the document is corrupted as you show.  If I change the field name `"document"` to `"doc"`, the import works correctly.  I suspect Compass is using the field name `"document"` for some internal reason and when an imported document has the same field name, bad things happen.  I wonder if there are other _"fragile"_ field names.  BTW, a concise `jq` filter could transform all your `"document"` field names, if you want.

Comment: I hope you report the bug.

Comment: @rickhg12hs thank you! I think you're right about "document" field. It really may be related to this, I'll try to do some research and update my question later if it's really related to specific field names within the document. Also, I'll report this